# Configuring Pylint for Django projects

Tags: django, pylint

G'Day,

I have a number of Django projects and a number of other Python projects as git repositories. I have pre-commit hook that runs Pylint on my code before allowing me to commit it - this hook doesn't know whether the project is a Django application or a vanilla Python project.

For all my Django projects, I have a structure like:

```
> my_django_project
|-- manage.py
|-- settings.py
|--> apps
   |--> my_django_app
      |-- models.py
      |-- admin.py
```

Now, when I run pylint on this project, it gives me errors like:

```
F:  4,0: Unable to import 'my_django_app.models'
```

for `my_django_app.admin` module for example.

How to do I configure Pylint, so that when it is going over my django projects (not vanilla python projects), it knows that the `my_django_project/apps` should also be in the `sys.path`? Normally, `manage.py` adds it to the `sys.path`.

Thanks!

Comment: Are `my_django_project/apps` and `my_django_project/apps/my_django_app` normal Python packages? If so, where are `my_django_project/apps/__init__.py` and `my_django_project/apps/my_django_app/__init__.py`?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at init_hook in pylint configuration file.

```
init-hook=import sys; sys.path.insert(0, 'my_django_project/apps');
```

You will obviously need a configuration file per Django application, and run pylint as, e.g.

```
pylint --rcfile=pylint.conf my_django_project
```

Comment: Best is to keep the .rcfile inside the project and then simply set `init-hook=import sys; sys.path.insert(0, 'apps');`. This way you can share the project with devs without hardcoding the path

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this doesn't fully answer your question, but I suggest to use [django-lint](http://chris-lamb.co.uk/projects/django-lint/), to avoid warnings like:

```
F:  4: Unable to import 'myapp.views'
E: 15: MyClass.my_function: Class 'MyClass' has no 'objects' member
E: 77: MyClass.__unicode__: Instance of 'MyClass' has no 'id' member
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Koterpillar's great answer, you can also configure your pre-commit hook to change the current directory to `my_django_project` and run pylint from there.